# How to display rich text html in the list display of Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

In models.py

```
description = models.RichTextField
```

In admin.py

```
list_display = ['description']
```

I admin panel description is displayed like this :

```
<p><strong>bold description:&nbsp;</strong>adding a description</p>
```

expected is this:
**bold description**: adding a description

beginner in Django assistance in this would be appreciated

Comment: Please try to be more specific.

Comment: after adding description from admin panel in editor it's getting displayed as a string of Html I want it to display as it is for instance text inside strong tags should be displayed bold @TalhaQuddoos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [format_html](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html) to mark your content as safe

```
from django.utils.html import format_html

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...

    list_display = ['get_description', ]

    def get_description(self, obj):
       return format_html(obj)
    get_description.short_description = 'description'
```